# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el sonido suene solo una vez cuando suelte el botón?

Tags: java, android, sonido

Estoy haciendo que el un imagebutton suene un efecto de sonido, pero algo sale mal, cuando presiono el objeto suena (ahí va bien), pero cuando suelto el botón me vuelve a sonar.. pero solo quiero que suene una sola vez al presionar.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton c4;

    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int son_c4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        c4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibc4);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(4).build();
        }else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }

        son_c4=soundPool.load(this, R. raw.c4,1);   

        /*c4.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                soundPool.play(son_c4,1,1,9,0,1);
                return false;
            }
        });*/

        c4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                soundPool.play(son_c4,1,1,0,0,0);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Es correcto el OnTouchListener solo detecta cuando das clic (ACTION_DOWN) y cuando dejas de dar clic (ACTION_UP) para detener la reproducción del sonido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso te recomiendo usar un [OntouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), de esta forma al dar click (`ACTION_DOWN`) se reproduce y cuando dejes de tocar el ImageView (`ACTION_UP`), se detiene la reproducción:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                     soundPool.play(son_c4,1,1,0,0,0);
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                   
                    soudPool.stop();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: gracias, funciono, pero en la linea de soundPool.stop();  me subraya en el vacio del parentesis en rojo, le agregue la variable son_c4.. nose si iba eso o habia que poner otra cosa...

Answer (score 0):

Cuando quieres que deje de sonar da la orden:

```
sounPool.stop();
```

Pedes establecer el tiempo de duración del sonido con 'Handler':

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void  run() {
                       soudPool.stop();
                    }
                },3000)
```

1000 =1 segundo;
2000 = 2 seg.;
3000=3 seg.
Y así sucesivamente

Comment: como podria hacer para que el sonido se baje con degrades?